# pyinstaller issue EXE error:"cannot open self abc or archive abc.pkg"

Tags: python, oracle, exe, pyinstaller

I am making an exe file from python(.py) using pyinstaller. The code requires connection to SQL database through cx_Oracle. Exe file gets created successfully and runs on my PC properly. However, when I share it with a team member of mine, it does not run on some other PC and gives this error: 
**"cannot open self abc or archive abc.pkg"** (abc being the name of exe).

It would be very nice if someone could help on the same.

Comment: did you run it on Windows ? It may not work on other systems - ie. Linux, Unix, MacOS.

Comment: is this full error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: first check on PyInstaller page [When Things Go Wrong](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html) and [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html)

Comment: Does the user have the necessary Oracle client libraries?  Or did you package them somehow (which should be possible if pyinstaller can bundle DLLs, since you are both on Windows)